# Forge Viewer - Convert-utils for glTF not working

Tags: autodesk, gltf, forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We are trying to seek [forge-convert-utils](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils) in order to get a list of the gltf's from the urns sent. When we reach to construct a new ManifesterHelper(), this returns undefined, forcing the loop to advance for next urn (with the obvious same result).

```
 urnsPerProject.forEach(async urn => {
   try {
     const auth = {
       client_id: process.env.FORGE_CLIENT_ID,
       client_secret: process.env.FORGE_SECRET
     }

     const parsedUrn = Buffer.from(urn).toString('base64')

     const mdClient = new ModelDerivativeClient(
       auth,
       'https://developer.api.autodesk.com',
       Region.EMEA
     )

     const helper = new ManifestHelper(await mdClient.getManifest(parsedUrn))
     const derivatives = helper.search({ type: 'resource', role: 'graphics' })

     const readerOptions = {
       log: console.log
     }

     const writerOptions = {
       deduplicate: true,
       skipUnusedUvs: true,
       center: false,
       log: console.log
     }

     const writer = new GltfWriter(writerOptions)

     const filteredDerivatives = derivatives.filter(derivative => {
       // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
       // @ts-ignore
       return derivative.mime === 'application/autodesk-svf'
     })

     for (const derivative of filteredDerivatives) {
       const reader = await SvfReader.FromDerivativeService(
         urn,
         derivative.guid,
         auth
       )

       const scene = await reader.read(readerOptions)
       console.log('scene', scene)
     }
   } catch (error) {
     console.error('error', error)
   }
 })
```

[error: requested resource does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqIPy.png)

[debugged parsed urn parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwn8A.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in here was solved!

1st - I missed to replace the '/' by '_' at the base64 parsedUrn

```
const parsedUrn = Buffer.from(urn).toString('base64').replace('/', '_')
```

2nd - I was choosing EMEA as Region, but I had to pass US

Great thx to #PetrBroz from #Autodesk

Answer (score 0):

Romero,

Can you submit an Issue on the GitHub repo here:
https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils/issues/new

Also, it will be super helpful if you can attach the example SVF files, you are trying to convert, so we can debug the error.

That will speed things up, for sure.

You can also ping me on slack directly ;-)

Comment: Good morning Mr. Beale. About SVF attachment, I should tell that we are trying to translate an urn list that comes directly from BIM360 user models, in order to have available any of these geoms at a same viewer. In this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwn8A.png it can be seen that the format differs from the urn samples, so I don't know if we are missing or failing some step. Thank You

Comment: I think it's related to your URN. When getting derivative URN from BIM360, from the details of the latest version of your file : ```data > relationships > derivatives > data > id``` , the URN is already in base64 so you don't need to convert it. If you start your code by doing this, this is probably not the right URN ! ;)